# XPath concat two children

Tags: html, xpath

I know this is a commonly asked question (I found [Concatenate multiple node values in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996965/concatenate-multiple-node-values-in-xpath) [XPath joining multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075700/xpath-joining-multiple-elements) and a few others), but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I've got the following HTML:

```
<div class="product-card__price__new"><span class="product-card__price__euros">0.</span> <span class="product-card__price__cents">69</span></div>
```

From which I need to extract the 0.69. I tried the following XPATH:

```
'.//*[@class="product-card__price__new"]/concat(/span/text(), following-sibling::span[1]/text)'
'.//*[@class="product-card__price__new"]/span/text()/concat(., following-sibling::span[1]/text)'
'.//*[@class="product-card__price__new"]/text()'
```

But I keep getting nothing. What would be the correct expression to extract it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler than this. The string value of an element is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes. So it's just

`string(.//*[@class="product-card__price__new"])`

and in many contexts you don't need the call on string() because it's implicit.

Most of the time when people use `text()` they are (a) over-complicating things and/or (b) getting it wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my other text() selectors as well.

Comment: Your suggestion actually returns `0. 69` because of the space between the two span-nodes. I would suggest `.//*[@class="product-card__price__new"]/string-join(span)` instead.